# Using readPassword method of Console?

Tags: java, console, passwords

When I try to use the method **readPassword()** to receive input from console as **char[]** then convert this input to a **string** as below

```
char[] pass = console.readPassword("Enter your DB password please : ");
String password = new String(pass);
```

it's give me an **output** as :-

```
Enter your DB password please :
```

and when I try to start typing my password **nothing typed to console ever !** any Suggestions ?

EDIT :- what I mean, I want to display * while typing.

Comment: That's exactly what that function is supposed to do.

Comment: Please read the docs for Console class.

Comment: i thought that it's displays * while typing

Answer (score 0):

The way the console reads passwords is by not displaying them in the console. If you test this and type where it says to, the console will read it, but not display it while you're typing.